# How to convert interrogation mark character in accented letters

Tags: cat, character-encoding, unicode, special-characters

I have a file containing accented letters

- with `cat`, I get interrogation marks

  ```
  voltm�tre
  ```
- with `less`, I get accented letters with brackets

  ```
  voltm<E8>tre
  ```
- with `vim`, I get the accented letter being displayed properly

  ```
  voltmètre
  ```

How can I modify my file so that accent are displayed properly with `cat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets), this might work:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: in my case it replaced the characters by spaces. didn't work